# Does FDT support multi threaded debugging

Tags: fdt

We've switched back onto the Flex bandwagon with FlexJS - does FDT support putting breakpoints on Worker threads, and having the code execution stop on that breakpoint? IntelliJ does not allow for that, and Adobe does not support Flash Builder for El Capitan, so it's too slow to use. We need to switch to another IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, FDT does support multi threaded debugging.